# Query free timeslots in MongoDB using unix timestamps

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB and probably this is a common use case, but I didn't find an answer to this specific case.

I would like to filter out those MongoDB documents where a timeslot in booking is still free, so there is no overlapping with existing bookings.

My collection entries:

```
  {
    "_id": "5efc9f89749c983ffd58c55f",
    "training": "football",
    "bookings": [
      {
        "from": 1593607419,
        "to": 1593622800
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "5efc9f89749c983ffd58c55f",
    "training": "baseball",
    "bookings": [
      {
        "from": 1593607419,
        "to": 1593622800
      },
      {
        "from": 1593687419,
        "to": 1593722800
      }
    ]
  }
```

Expected result with input "From: 1593500000" and "To: 1593600000".

```
  {
    "_id": "5efc9f89749c983ffd58c55f",
    "training": "football"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5efc9f89749c983ffd58c55f",
    "training": "baseball"
  }
```

Both documents have free timeslots (no overlapping with existing bookings).

Expected result with input "From: 1593670000" and "To: 1593690000".

```
  {
    "_id": "5efc9f89749c983ffd58c55f",
    "training": "football"
  }
```

Only football is returned, because the queried values overlaps with the second booking entry of baseball.

Is it possible to do this with a single query? For example using between or something like that?
Or is there a better approach/best practice?

I implement the query with Spring Data REST, but just some help with the mongodb query would already be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a logical problem, I'm not familiar with Spring Data, your query should look like this.

```
{
  bookings: {
    $not: {
      $elemMatch: {
        $or: [{
          from: { $gte: start, $lte: end }
        }, {
          to: { $gte: start, $lte: end }
        }]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/j5cwaf8M49h)

Comment: your answer is already very helpful, thank you! Unfortunatly I also need all documents with free timeslots between two bookings. Example: start: 1593622801, end: 1593687418. => should return both documents football and baseball, because there is still a free timeslot for baseball between both the bookings. Do you have an idea how this case can be considered? [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ty-N0ZAaFWu)

Comment: What I can think of right now, is to convert the range to discrete values according to your smallest increment possible. The we can try to apply set operations on those values. What are the smallest increment you can to calculate? 1 second? 1 minute? 15 minute? 1 hour?

Comment: The smallest increment is one minute.

Comment: @Dennis Sorry to confuse you with those discrete values approach I have misunderstood the requirement. I thought the range given was start: 1593607419, end: 1593722800. Please check the updated answer, I made some logical mistake in the initial answer

Comment: that's exactly what I need. Thanks for your help, I appreciate it very much!